# How to keep text formating in a call to a template in XSL?

Tags: xslt, styling

I have the following code who calls a template :

```
<xsl:call-template name="LigneDonnee">
    <xsl:with-param name="text">Les émissions de CO<fo:inline font-size="6pt">2</fo:inline> :</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select='InfoGenerale/EmissionCO2' /></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

Which call the following template :

```
<xsl:template name="LigneDonnee">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:param name="value"/>

  <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="9.5in" padding-bottom="6pt" padding-top="6pt">
  <fo:table-column column-width="6.0in"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="1.70in"/>
  <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell text-align="right" vertical-align="middle">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:if test="$value != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select='translate(format-number($value, "### ### ### ##0.######"),".",",")' />
          </xsl:if>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>    
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that the `CO<fo:inline font-size="6pt">2</fo:inline>` seems to be transformed to a mere `CO2` by the `<xsl:value-of select="$text" />`.

How to avoid/circumvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the `value-of` to `xsl:copy-of`

Try:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$text" />
```